# I want this select to have an object value, this works but I can't show the title of the selected object, does anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want this select to have an object value, this works but I can't show the title of the selected object, does anyone know why?
my code is:

```
const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");

const litaCategorias = [
                          {
                              "id": 2,
                              "titulo": "test",
                              "descripcion": "descripcion",
                               }];   
                     
const handleChangeCategoria = (value) => {
        setCategoria(value)
        console.log(value)
   }

 <Select
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        value={categoria.titulo}
        onChange={e => handleChangeCategoria(e.target.value)}
        labelWidth={0}
        placeholder={"Seleccione un destino"}
    >
            {litaCategorias.map(categoria => {
            return (
              <option
                value={categoria}
                key={categoria.titulo}
                >
                {categoria.titulo}
              </option>
            );
                })}
    </Select>
```

Comment: is there any error. in the logs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have double checked the `Select` component in material-ui. It provides props api `value` with description:

> If the value is an object it must have reference equality with the option in order to be selected. If the value is not an object, the string representation must match with the string representation of the option in order to be selected.

You you should memorize you array `litaCategorias`. to make `reference equality`.

Should use `useMemo` to memorized array.

```
const litaCategorias = useMemo(() => [ { "id": 2, "titulo": "test", "descripcion": "descripcion", }], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're setting the param in your callback in the `.map` function to `categoria` which is defined in the state and is initialized to an empty string. This line here - `{litaCategorias.map(categoria => {`. The `option` value in the select dropdown is not getting the correct object because of this.

Try something like this instead:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState("");

  const litaCategorias = [
    { id: 1, titulo: "test", descripcion: "descripcion" },
    { id: 2, titulo: "test2", descripcion: "descripcion2" }
  ];

  const handleChangeCategoria = (value) => {
    setCategoria(value);
    console.log(value);
  };
  return (
    <select
      value={categoria.titulo}
      onChange={(e) => handleChangeCategoria(e.target.value)}
    >
      {litaCategorias.map((cat) => {
        return (
          <option value={cat.titulo} key={cat.id}>
            {cat.titulo}
          </option>
        );
      })}
    </select>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-mountain-0r4p6?file=/src/App.js